# How to find the largest array from a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the maximum value from an element in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189479/get-the-maximum-value-from-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array)
>   [find max() of specific multidimensional array value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426972/find-max-of-specific-multidimensional-array-value-in-php)

Iam trying to find out the largest array from multi dimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment] => ayya
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 210029c5d80d8259d1599c9a
            [username] => pappa
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment] => sdfsd
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 08f6a34f96bdeef2903ddaf4
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comment] => 159
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 4da385124793336339268782
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [comment] => s
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 299c77c52ee087e468e23e82
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [comment] => jh
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 523c18820d8b8db827a240ad
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 2
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [comment] => jh
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => 9f824c11b0ecafcc38c09f4c
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 1
            [down] => 1
            [vote] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [comment] => jh
            [commented_on] => 17/03/12
            [ckey] => c97e7ad4d205220c4b8b0332
            [username] => jesse
            [up] => 1
            [down] => 0
            [vote] => 1
        )

)
```

I would like to get the array having highest votes.
Highest means the array having highest vote

I have used the following code, but it is not working.

```
$large=array();
                    foreach($final2 as $f1){

                        foreach($final2 as $f2){

                            if($f1['vote']>$f2['vote'])
                                $large=$f1;

                        }

                    }
```

Comment: $large=array();
      foreach($final2 as $f1){
       
       foreach($final2 as $f2){
        
        if($f1['vote']>$f2['vote'])
         $large=$f1;
       
       }
       
      }
      op($large);

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code. It's unreadable in comments.

Comment: @sunilkumar you seem to be on the right track, I'm assuming the second `foreach` is a copy & paste error since it's not needed.

Comment: just wrote a oneliner for it `$maxs = $multi[array_keys(array_map(function( $row ){ return count($row['vote']); }, $multi ), max(array_map(function( $row ){ return count($row['vote']); }, $multi )))[0]];`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK array size is counted from the number of elements it has.

So may be this will help

```
$largeArraySize = 0;

foreach($arraylist as $array) {
   if(count($array) > $largeArraySize) {
     $largeArray = $array;
   }
}

// Hence $largeArray has the largest
print_r($largeArray);
```

Unless a large array come this code will take the first occurrence as the largest.

Comment: you need to change $largeArraySize to equal `count($array);` each time a new larger array is found.

Comment: or a 1 liner : `$max = max( array_map(function( $row ){ return count($row); }, $multi ) )`

Answer (score 0):

Since the array is only nested one level deep and all the sub-arrays have the same structure, just loop through the outer array and track the maximum value seen so far.  Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information such as whether the array is already sorted on number of votes, the only option you have left is a `O(n)` linear search.

```
$max = 0;
$max_index = 0;

if( count($outer_array) > 0 )
{
    // There are elements in the outer array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($outer_array); $i++ )
    {
        if( isset($outer_array[$i]["vote"]) )
        {
            if( $outer_array[$i]["vote"] > $max )
            {
                $max_index = $i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Error condition, malformed array
            // Do something here, maybe throw exception?
        } 
    }
}
else
{
    // Error condition - outer array is empty, could also throw exception here...
    $max = -1; // Assume votes cannot be negative
    $max_index = -1;
}

if( $max_index != -1 )
{
    // Success
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea to get the highest number of votes in the inner arrays:

```
$array = array(
    array('votes' => 2),
    array('votes' => 3),
    array('votes' => 0),
    array('votes' => 1)
);

$votes = 0;
$key = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if($array[$i]['votes'] > $votes){
    $key = $i;
    $votes = $array[$i]['votes'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$large=array('vote' => -1);
foreach($final2 as $f1){
    if ($f1['vote'] > $large['vote']) {
         $large=$f1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(.....)

$max_votes = 0;
foreach ($array as $data) {
    $vote = $data['vote'];
    if ($vote > $max_vote) {
        $max_vote = $vote;
    }     
}

$max = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
   if ($data['vote'] == $max_vote) {
       $max[] = $key;
   }
}
```

$max will now hold all of the arrays with the highest number of votes being the value of $max_votes.