# Finding max with multiple key filter inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have script which needs to find the star performer of the month.

This is sample data

```
 $data = array (
          [0] = array(
               "tasks_done" => 5,
                "rating" => 5),
          [1] = array(
               "tasks_done" => 4,
                "rating" => 5),
          [2] = array(
               "tasks_done" => 3,
                "rating" => 5),
          [3] = array(
               "tasks_done" => 5,
               "rating" => 5)
       );
```

So the question is to find the person with max tasks done and max number of rating. Is this possible using any algorithm of by simple php code.

References Sample to find max number in array  :

[find max() of specific multidimensional array value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426972/find-max-of-specific-multidimensional-array-value-in-php)

But nothing seems to work. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make your question clear?

Comment: Which hold more weight when comparasion??? Or your want to find max separately?

Comment: @KrisRoofe find max separately with two filters  findmax(task_done) and findmax(rating)  which must output one result

Comment: `max(array_column($array, 'tasks_done'))`

Comment: This is a simple task - iterate over array and compare values.

Comment: @KrisRoofe your code will only find person with max number of tasks done. i want with both max no of tasks and max no of rating

Comment: @u_mulder can you please provide a sample code with fiddle or else

Comment: Make an effort and try something. Just coming here and waiting for a code is a bad approach.

Comment: @u_mulder    i already tried many solutions and  I also provided one reference link in the question. Please read it again.

Comment: Providing a link somewhere does not mean that you tried something. Same to `I tried many solutions`.

Comment: tasks_done & ratting is interlinked? means depends on each other ?

Comment: @pAsh yes it is

Comment: I solve it by adding tasks_done & ratting... check answer

Answer (score 0):

I have sort by rating first and second tasks_done.

Please check below code,

```
$data = array();
$data[0]=array("tasks_done" => 5,"rating" => 5);
$data[1]=array("tasks_done" => 4,"rating" => 5);
$data[2]=array("tasks_done" => 3,"rating" => 3);
$data[3]=array("tasks_done" => 5,"rating" => 6);
$data[4]=array("tasks_done" => 6,"rating" => 2);
$data[5]=array("tasks_done" => 3,"rating" => 6);
$temp_array = array();
$output = array();
foreach($data as $k=>$values){
    $temp_array['tasks_done'][$values['tasks_done']][$k]=$values['tasks_done'];
    $temp_array['rating'][$values['rating']][$k]=$values['rating'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
krsort($temp_array['tasks_done']);
krsort($temp_array['rating']);
foreach($temp_array['rating'] as $k=>$v){
    $check = checkUpper($v,$temp_array['tasks_done']);
    foreach($v as $k1=>$v1){
        $output[]=array(
            "tasks_done"=>$check[$k1],
            "rating"=>$v1
        );
    }
}
function checkUpper($array_check,$array){
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($array as $keys=>$values){
        foreach($values as $key=>$value){
            if(array_key_exists($key,$array_check)){
                $tmp[$key]=$value;
            }
        }
    }
    arsort($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
```

Output,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 5
            [rating] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 3
            [rating] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 5
            [rating] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 4
            [rating] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 3
            [rating] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [tasks_done] => 6
            [rating] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using mysql with order by parameter.   Thank you folks for your help.