# Get max of each unique key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array similar to the below. I am trying to get the max weight value for each unique key in the array e.g. Store A = 230, Store B = 180, Store C = 439, and the same for the brand key.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [cid] => 123 [weight] => 230 [store] => Store A [brand] => Brand A)
[1] => Array ( [cid] => 124 [weight] => 180 [store] => Store B [brand] => Brand B ) 
[2] => Array ( [cid] => 131 [weight] => 439 [store] => Store C [brand] => Brand B ) 
[3] => Array ( [cid] => 128 [weight] => 124 [store] => Store B [brand] => Brand B ) 
[4] => Array ( [cid] => 130 [weight] => 249 [store] => Store C [brand] => Brand C ) 
)
```

I can get the max weight value of the entire array (using max(), but need the max weight for each respective key. Been messing with this for hours and not getting anywhere!

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: this looks like similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189479/get-the-maximum-value-from-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$maxes = array();

foreach ($array as $i) {
    if (!isset($maxes[$i['store']]) || $maxes[$i['store']] < $i['weight']) {
        $maxes[$i['store']] = $i['weight'];
    }
}

var_dump($maxes);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. How would I return the relevant 'cid' value as opposed to the weight value in the outputted array? Changing the last 'weight' to 'cid' gives a strange result. i.e. the resulting cid is not the id of the heaviest. thanks.

Comment: Store more than just the weight in the maxes array. I'll leave it up to you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = $array() // Your array
$max = array();

foreach ( $array as $product) {
    if ( ! isset( $max[ $product['store'] ] ) ) {
        $max[ $product['store'] ] = $product['weight'];
    } else {
        $max[ $product['store'] ] = max( $max[ $product['store'] ], $product['weight'] );
    }
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eF4ZQ7

Comment: Great thanks. deceze's solution is slightly cleaner, but both solutions work great.