# Minimum and maximum from array of months in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

i have an array of date in php like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => April-2014
            [total_booking] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => May-2014
            [total_booking] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => June-2014
            [total_booking] => 25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => October-2013
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month] => July-2014
            [total_booking] => 4
        )

)
```

i want to find the minimum and maximum month from this array. currently i am using `foreach()`  function and comparing each element. but i think this is not ideal if the array is bigger. is there any other option?
**expected output from the above array**

```
minimum:October-2013
maximum :July-2014
```

**update**
now i have converted this array to following structure

```
  Array
(
    [October-2013] => 5
    [April-2014] => 2
    [June-2014] => 17
    [August-2014] => 1
    [May-2014] => 4
    [July-2014] => 8
)
```

then for finding minimum and maximum by

```
natcasesort($testKeys = array_keys($newarray));

                    echo 'Min: ' . $testKeys[0] . ', max: ' . $testKeys[count($testKeys) - 1] . '<br />';
```

but i am getting output

```
Min: October-2013, max: July-2014  .
```

expected maximum is  `August-2014`.

can any one find the solution?

Comment: Other implementations using `array_walk`, `array_reduce` or similar are possible – but in the end all of those will have to loop through all array elements one way or another … Apart from that, this is a typical “premature optimization” question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189479/get-the-maximum-value-from-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: is that two dimensional array ? seem so

Comment: @Skram  i want to comapre date values.

Comment: @Mubo yes it is two dim array

Answer (score 1):

For that array structure, iterating into it to find the max and min is the only way to go.

Unless you can make a 1D array that looks like this:

```
array(201406, 201302, 201312)
```

You can then use PHP's built-in [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) functions.

For that 1D array above and your original array, you can use the booking ID as the index. So that when you find out the max/min value from the 1D array, you can reference the associated booking details using the array index.

Comment: can you do an example.. ie, hw to make into id array and find min and max?

Comment: So how did you generate the 2D array in your original post?

Comment: can i find from the follng array structure  `Array ( [October-2013] => 2 [April-2014] => 2 [June-2014] => 25 [May-2014] => 4 [July-2014] => 4 ) `