# How to parse in PHP a column from a JSON array with variable and display maximum value?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array, I get it from the REST API using `curl` and I want to get all the numbers from the **"c"** column and then find the **maximum**.

***function part of my code***

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-domain.com/v3/instruments/" . $ticker . "/candles?&price=A&from=" . $first . "&to=" . $second . "&granularity=D");
// get stringified data/output. See CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
$data = curl_exec($ch);
// get info about the request
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
$json_string = $data;
$jsondata = ($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
print_r($jsondata); //below get the answer
```

//(***print_r output***)

```
{
"instrument":"EUR_USD",
"granularity":"D",
"candles":[
{
"complete":true,
"volume":32813,
"time":"2017-01-02T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04711",
"h":"1.04908",
"l":"1.03413",
"c":"1.04061"
}
},
{
"complete":true,
"volume":34501,
"time":"2017-01-03T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04076",
"h":"1.05009",
"l":"1.03907",
"c":"1.04908"
}
},
{
"complete":true,
"volume":52627,
"time":"2017-01-04T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04911",
"h":"1.06161",
"l":"1.04816",
"c":"1.06083"
}}]}
```

Comment: Seeing the output this is probably not the `print_r` result. To print the JSON in a nicer way: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($jsondata, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Also, what have you tried ? Please show your attempt.

Comment: `echo $obj['candles'][0]['ask']['c']` he me lifts the number of only the first array 1.04061

Comment: So write a foreach loop to process the array `foreach ( $obj['candles'] as $candles)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly [follow link Get the maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189479/get-the-maximum-value-from-an-element-in-a-multidimensional-array) `$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);

    $max = 0;
    foreach($obj as $objj)
    {
        if($objj->candles->ask->c > $max)
        {
            $max = $objj->c;
        }
        var_dump($max);
    }` **I tried, but why the not goes** output `
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following to get desired output.

1. Decode json
2. Map array
3. Sort

Snippet

```
$data = '{
"instrument":"EUR_USD",
"granularity":"D",
"candles":[
{
"complete":true,
"volume":32813,
"time":"2017-01-02T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04711",
"h":"1.04908",
"l":"1.03413",
"c":"1.04061"
}
},
{
"complete":true,
"volume":34501,
"time":"2017-01-03T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04076",
"h":"1.05009",
"l":"1.03907",
"c":"1.04908"
}
},
{
"complete":true,
"volume":52627,
"time":"2017-01-04T22:00:00.000000000Z",
"ask":{
"o":"1.04911",
"h":"1.06161",
"l":"1.04816",
"c":"1.06083"
}}]}';

$arr = json_decode($data,true);

$c = array_map( function ($in){
return  $in['ask']['c'];
}, $arr['candles']);

sort($c);

echo 'Min is: '.current($c)."\n";
echo 'Max is: '.end($c);
```

Output

```
Min is: 1.04061
Max is: 1.06083
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/YsJ3a)

Docs

1. [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
2. [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array of the close prices using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with an [anynomous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and then get the highest value using [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
// This will return an array of the close prices
$close_prices = array_map(function ($candle) {
    return $candle['ask']['c'];
},
$jsondata['candles']); // <-- Of course send the candlesticks array

// Now get the highest value in the close prices array
$highest = max($close_prices);


echo 'Maximum EUR/USD value: 1 EUR = ' . $highest . ' USD';
// Maximum EUR/USD value: 1 EUR = 1.06083 USD
```

Same code, shorter:

```
$highest = max(array_map(function($c) { return $c['ask']['c']; }, $jsondata['candles']));
```